# Rolling Timer Array for Calculating Averages

Tags: timer, average, moving-average, rolling-computation

**Language:** C++

**Development Environment:** Microsoft Visual C++

**Libraries Used:** MFC

**Problem:** This should be fairly simple, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. I'm attempting to calculate a rolling average over a given amount of time - let's say five seconds. Every second, my program receives a data message containing some numerical information, including the CPU idle time during the process.

I want to be able to show the user an average CPU idle time over a five second period. I was thinking about using just an array and storing a value every five seconds, but I'm not sure how to do the rolling portion. Unless there is some other built-in method for doing rolling calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it would actually be better to implement immediate feedback regarding idle percentage, which is much easier to code.